# How to install plugins in individual sites on a wordpress network?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I'm trying to install plugins in my wordpress subsites instead of network activate that plugin. But i'm not seeing any "add new" link in my subsite plugin area. How to install plugins in my individual sites. Am i missing something?.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Install plugin in networ admin as usual for multisite.
2. Do not activate plugin for whole network.
3. Go to admin of individual site and enable plugin there for that site alone.

Comment: Hi i activated the plugins for whole network and now i don't see any plugin updates on network site? any solution?

Comment: Hello from 2020, @Rarst what if I want to hide that plugin from listing into another individual sites so they dont activate that

Answer (score 0):

a) Install the applications to the maintain. 
b) and active the site from your subdomain or sub-directly. 
c) you need to be network admin when you're trying to active the plugins for specific domain.

Answer (score 0):

Of simply use this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jamjar-plugin-installer/

it allows you to install plugins on individual sites without using network installation.